# Why is speed * travel duration = total distance?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$V(n) = $ the spaceship's speed, when using $n$ engines.

$T(n) = $ the spaceship's maximum travel duration when using $n$ engines (the spaceship runs out of fuel).

Asked is what the total distance is when using $n$ engines. I want to know why the correct answer is $V(n) * T(n)$ rather than $\frac{V(n)}{T(n)}$ which I initially gave as the answer to an algebra 2 assignment. I figured speed is essentialy $distance/time$. And that's when I got confused.

Comment: This is not a math question.

Comment: @AlexSilva did you not see the "algebra 2 assignment."

Comment: Looks like somebody's teacher entertains strange ideas about how spaceships work.

Comment: @Bot: As bonus questions in a logic 2 course I gave my students films and plot points to analyze. Doesn't make it a mathematical question though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's a question from khanacademy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V(n)=\frac{distance}{time}=\frac{distance}{T(n)}$ (this is true by definition. Think for example about the unit for speed: meters/second)

We want to solve for distance:

$distance=V(n)*T(n)$

Comment: You may want to add that the first equality is true *by definition*: that's what speed (or velocity) *is*.

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

the speed is $\frac{distance}{T(n)}$, and therefore the distance is $V(n)\cdot T(n)$